# Not Able to Login to PHP Applications

Tags: php, linux, server

I just did a cpanel restore on one of my accounts; this account had 2 web applications, one crowdfunding, one project management. The crowdfunding is quite advance but the project management script is very small and very simple, BOTH are using php. I moved from VPS to Dedicated server, still using WHM and Cpanel. I copied over the php configuration over.

When I type in a wrong password, I get the error message, when I type in the right password, it takes me back to the login page, can't get in, no error message; this happens for both web applications.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using linux Centos 6, 64bit.

Comment: Check the php version that you have in new server with the old one.

Comment: "I get the error message" - what error message?

Comment: Just the normal php echo message saying your password is not correct.

Comment: Can you still connect to your MySQL servers using the credentials for each application? (Please use @halfer when responding to me, or the appropriate username for others. This way I get a notification, and will miss it otherwise).

Comment: @halfer, yeah, I can. I think it's a session problem on just this one account on my dedicated server? http://icmin.in/ shows another session error.

Comment: Try a [session example](https://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to test it. Maybe the session folder is not being set up correctly by PHP, and has incorrect permissions. Make sure you turn errors on.

Answer (score 0):

php.ini /tmptest to /tmp. Old server session save location was at /tmptest, new server didn't have that directory so no sessions were being saved. Problem solved :)